# Coordinates of vertices from adjacency matrix; application to crop rotations represented by stochastic transition matrix

Tags: r, plot, graphics, igraph, adjacency-matrix

**Context:** I am trying to plot crop rotations from transition matrix describing the changes from one crop to another. For those wondering, using transition matrix to represent crop rotations has been published but the reference is not about making the plots; see:

> Castellazzi, M.S., Wood, G.A., Burgess, P.J., Morris, J., Conrad,
> K.F., Perry, J.N., 2008. A systematic representation of crop
> rotations. Agricultural Systems 97, 26–33.
> https://doi.org/10.1016/j.agsy.2007.10.006

By *stochastic matrix* I mean a square matrix representing the transition probability from Ci to Cj in one step. The sum of each row is equal to one.

**This comes down to use a stochastic transition matrix as an adjacency matrix to build a weighted and directed graph**. This can be done using `diagram::plotmat()` and `igraph::graph_from_data_frame()` but I just can't find out how to order vertices and make the edges look "nice".

Expected plot: [image: Expected output]

The matrix I would like to use looks like this:

```
> transmat
   C1 C2  C3  C4 C5
C1  0  1 0.0 0.0  0
C2  0  0 0.5 0.5  0
C3  0  0 0.0 0.0  1
C4  0  0 0.0 0.0  1
C5  1  0 0.0 0.0  0

> dput(transmat)
structure(list(C1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), C2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    C3 = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), C4 = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), C5 = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("C1", "C2", 
"C3", "C4", "C5"))
```

**Attempt with `diagram::plotmat()`:**

```
## With diagram::plotmat ----------------------------------------------------

plot.new()
plotmat(t(transmat), 
        pos = c(1,1,2,1), # non-0 count in each line of transmat
        curve = 0.3, 
        absent = 0, # don't connect crops linked by 0
        arr.type = "triangle",
        arr.pos = 0.6,
        box.type = "rect",
        box.prop=0.3,
        box.lwd=2,
        shadow.size = 0,
        cex.txt=0.8,
        endhead = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image: Output using diagram::plotmat]

**Another example with `igraph::graph_from_data_frame()` and `layout = layout_as_tree()`:**

Expected plot:
[image: Expected plot complex ex]

The associated matrix:

```
> complex_ex
     C1   C2  C3  C4   C5
C1 0.00 1.00 0.0 0.0 0.00
C2 0.00 0.00 0.5 0.5 0.00
C3 0.25 0.25 0.0 0.0 0.50
C4 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 1.00
C5 0.75 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.25

> dput(complex_ex)
structure(list(C1 = c(0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.75), C2 = c(1, 0, 0.25, 
0, 0), C3 = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), C4 = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), C5 = c(0, 
0, 0.5, 1, 0.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"))
```

The code I used:

```
# Some data transformation to make it work with igraph::graph_from_data_frame()

df_transmat <- as.data.frame(complex_ex)
df_transmat$from <- rownames(df_transmat)
df_transmat <- reshape(df_transmat,
                    idvar = "from",
                    varying = colnames(df_transmat)[1:(ncol(df_transmat)-1)],
                    times = colnames(df_transmat)[1:(ncol(df_transmat)-1)],
                    timevar = "to",
                    v.names = "change",
                    direction = "long")
rownames(df_transmat) <- NULL
rotation <- subset(df_transmat, subset = df_transmat$change != 0)

# The plot 

g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(rotation, directed = TRUE)

plot(g1, 
     layout = layout_as_tree(g1, root = "C1"),
     edge.arrow.mode = 2,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     edge.curved = 0,
     edge.width = 0.5,
     vertex.label.cex = 1, 
     vertex.label.font = 2,
     vertex.shape = "rectangle", 
     vertex.color = "white",
     vertex.size = 50,
     vertex.size2 = 30,
     vertex.label.dist = 0,
     vertex.label.color = "black")
```

The output:

[image: example 2 output]

Comment: Could you clarify what is wrong with the plot output that you were able to get? Is it that it does not arrange the nodes such that left-right is the edge direction?

Comment: @JoshPurtell, yes but not only, rows and links are not the way I would like them to be; it looks messy in my opinion. Plus, this example is very simple, sometime the rotation is much more complicated (some example are in the cited paper), then it becomes very important that all nodes are in the right order.

Comment: In fact I got the plot using `plot()` functions but it require very complicated code and works only for linear rotations *i.e* it is not able to represent C2/C3/C4 links.

Comment: could you define the stoch. matrix in R code in your question? I think I have an approach I want to test .. I know I could simply define it as well, but it will help other viewers. Also ideally you would add a stoch matrix for one of the " more difficult" examples that you allude to, since it seems like a complete answer must be extensible to those as well

Comment: @JoshPurtell, definition added. I might use the wrong words, maybe it is more correct to say that here it is about trying to use a stochastic matrix as an adjacency matrix. Then the question could be "is there a graph algorithm in R that allow to plot an adjacency matrix preserving nodes order?"

Comment: I am working on the more complex example.

Comment: I would say that is a very similar but somewhat different problem. Do you care about indicating transition probabilities with edge width etc? Or are probabilities unimportant? That would determine whether it's a question of using stoch or adjacency in my opinion

Comment: Transition probabilities are not important, that would be the icing on the cake to keep them to, for ex, make the line thickness proportional to them.

Comment: @JoshPurtell, I have added a more complex example, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223107/discussion-between-josh-purtell-and-paul).